# Assign a boolean in PHP

Tags: php

Why does this assignment of a variable with a boolean value fail?

```
$result = 1 == 2;
```

Result: $result is empty. (Expecting `false`.)
I even tried this:

```
$result = 1 == 2 ? true : false;
```

Result: $result is empty.
Is this just not possible in PHP?

---

Edit for future reference: `$result` was in fact `false` in both cases; I simply assumed otherwise because I inspected its value by "echo"-ing it. (See comments.)

Comment: how are u testing the result? what happens when u do `$result = (1 == 1);`

Comment: I was simply echo-ing the result, and as jspcal said, "`false` becomes an empty string". I did not know this…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `var_dump($result)`

Using `echo` / `print` converts the value to a string (`false` becomes an empty string).

Comment: I did not know the "echo/print of false"-thing. Madness!